# Developing a subset of hypotheses based on anecdotal observations

Tags: introduction

I am wondering what the opinion is on how to go about this.

I have an area I want to investigate through a number of testable hypothesis. In the course of an introduction, I introduce the background for each question, laying the foundation for why I am testing this particular thing, but also this serves to explain why I think it may be observed and why I have directed my hypothesis in the way I have.

For example, in the paragraph section of my introduction (ignore the phrasing, just trying to get my point across):

> The positive relationship between X on Y has been shown in some
> previous work (Smith et al 2050, Jones and Jones 2060). We intend to
> test this response at a landscape-scale to test if such an effect is
> predictable and observable when scaled-up.
>
> In summary, I intend to test the following hypotheses:
>
> 1. X will positively respond to Y
> 2. X will produce more Z when Y is lower

How do I introduce Z if there is no background literature on this. For instance, if someone with a lot of hands-on experience in this field but no scientific background has observed this in the field and I wish to test it in a controlled experiment. Is it best to not even list it as a hypothesis and instead raise it as a novel result later in the study?

Comment: *Is it best to not even list it as a hypothesis and instead raise it as a novel result later in the study?* --- This is not clear. Did you find that less Z was produced when Y was lower and intend to add that as a H to make yourself look better?

Comment: No, absolutely not. I mean to say how can I make a prediction based on an anecdotal observation and then test it, **without** it seeming like I have just added an H post-hoc to make myself look better

Comment: But you *have* found that relation? And are now writing that paper? Or no data yet?

Comment: No data yet. I hope to test this in the future. My desire to test it is based on anecdotal observation rather than results of previous documented experiments, and that is what I am stuck at.